# What is the start date of entry for Canada TRV

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas

I would like to apply for a Canada visa and I am wondering what I should put in as the intended date of travel as I am still not sure when I would want to fly. Would the tourist visa have the start date of entry as the issue date of visa or as the intended date of travel? I tried searching this all over the internet but everyone talks about a 6 month stay period and validity of 10 years and expiry date of the visa. There is no mention of the start date of the visa. Can anyone who has applied let me know what the start date of the visa is ?

Comment: That's alright. I do hope some one can affirm this with some handy source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the best official source available is the visa itself.

If you look at the visa, you will see that there are only two dates printed on it, the issue date and the expiry date. There is no separate date for start of validity.

So there is no question, the visa is valid from the issue date until the expiry date.

[image: Canada temporary resident visa]

Comment: So when you applied for the visa, do you remember if the issue date is exactly the same date as you intended to fly ? Or is it the same as when you were asked to submit the passport ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille It was the date they printed the visa and placed it in the passport. Your visa will be valid already when you receive the passport back. And Canada normally issues multiple entry visas valid until one month before your passport expires.